# What is the best way to modify the date format in a Google Apps Scripts Method?

Tags: date, google-apps-script, format

I have searched the site for similar questions but I did not find an answer specific to my situation. I am trying to display the current date in this formate: dd-MMM-yy, without the UTC time at the end. In the past in other functions I was able to have success using this: .setNumberFormat but in the function I am working on now, it won't work and it displays the full date.

This is my code I am using it in:

```
function updateLTD(e) {
  // Code designed to insert current date to the "LTD" sheet.
  var date = new Date();

  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || !e.value) return;
  e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
}
```

How to make this work in my current code? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Try [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) is returns a string

Comment: It does not work but I am so net with Apps Script, perhaps I am not calling it correctly. I did a quick search and if I understand this suggestion, I need it to remain a date not a string so I can perform a calculation on it in the sheet. Any idea why it does not work in one method vs. the other? Thanks.

Comment: If you use a canonical form then the [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) understands then new Date() will return it to a Date() object.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I am honestly more confused now than when I started. I must let you know I am new to the App Scripts (JS?). I tried this: var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"); and it gives me a string and I cannot perform the calculations in the sheet. It outputs this: 2022-06-19T23:50:36Z. I tried this as you suggested : var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(year, monthIndex, day); and it does not return anything. Is there a way to output a date object in the same format as this did: .setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy")? Thanks

Comment: I think that when your script is run by OnEdit trigger (from your showing script, I guessed like that), the inserted date object is shown with the format of `dd-MMM-yy`. So, I cannot understand `but in the function I am working on now, it won't work and it displays the full date.`. I apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your current issue, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? But, if you are not executing your function with OnEdit trigger, can I ask you about the method for executing the function?

Comment: If you have a string like MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.  Then using the constructor on that string will produced the date as an object and you can get it's value by new Date("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").valueOf(). If the form is not correct you can always split it up to new Date(yyyy,m,d,H,m,s)

Comment: Cooper, I don't understand you are way above my level. Perhaps an example...?
Tanaike,  this is the code:   
function onEdit(e) {
   var date = new Date();

  if (e.range.columnStart != 1 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
}

Comment: Read the Date Constructor Link

Comment: Try `spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell,7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy");`

Comment: I removed the second example code but casue the question might have been confusing. The code you show me thank you Cooper is from an example of code thatt is already working for me..... It was to demonstrate what worked before and ask why the following code is not working -> This the code: 
       e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(date).setNumberFormat("dd-MMM-yy")

Comment: `the following code is not working` Just tested and the code is working, can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet?